# Processor Cycles spent on useful work is less when L1 access latency is high

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

I run a benchmark program on a processor simulator with two different configurations.

Config 1 has L1 access latency (hitDelay and missDelay as 1 cycle)
Config 2 has L1 access latency as 7 cycles.

The total number of dynamic instructions completed in both the runs of the same benchmark is 13743658, but the cycles attributed to completing and committing useful instructions is 68,782.17  in config 2 and 158,498.33 in Config 1.

So, what's bizarre about this is, the processor spends less cycles (68,782.17) when L1 access latency is 7 cycles as compared to 158,498.33 when L1 access latency is 1 cycle.

Can somebody explain why this would be the case. It seems counterintuitive.

Comment: Is the CPU superscalar?  Does it end up concentrating the work into fewer cycles, if there's enough ILP to hide the L1 latency?  The total cycles taken for the whole program is higher, right, with higher L1 latency?

Comment: Hi Peter - Yes, the CPU is superscalar. To be precise, it's a SESC simulator.

Comment: The total # of cycles with L1-latency of 7-cycles is higher than the total cycles with L1-latency of 1 cycle. This is because extra cycles are spent on waiting for the availability of Reservation Stations (Instruction Windows) because the load / store operations are slower. However, I still don't understand why the cycles spent on useful work is lower for Config-2 vs Config-1.

Comment: It's surprising to me, too.  There's not much info in your question about what the program does, or about other parts of the big picture, which is why I had to ask for more details.  When you say "cycles attributed to completing and committing useful instructions", do you mean that's how many cycles had any retired instructions, or that was counting cycles when the front-end was stalled waiting for the back-end to free space in the ROB, or what?

Comment: It's normal for retirement to be "bursty"; when one old instruction finally executes and is ready to retire, a bunch of later independent instruction may be able to retire in the next few cycles at the max rate.  Very short L1 latency may reduce the burstiness over small scales.  Over large scales, a cache miss can be hanging around for a long time, but 7-cycle L1 latency may group retirement into lots of smaller bursts, especially if the code is sensitive to L1d load-use latency.  (e.g. pointer-chasing in a tree or linked list, or just a couple levels of indirection via pointers.)